# Maximum size of dictionary variable?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

How much can be the maximum size of the json_data here?

```
with open("database.json") as data:
    json_data = json.load(data)
```

I need exact answer as there is some database processing logic there.
At the moment the code is working fine but the size of the file is 255kb at the moment and this file size will keep on increasing. Can anyone suggest where i should have the check for memory management.

Comment: It will at least depend on 1. how much memory you have, 2. whether Python is 32 or 64 bit, and 3. what kinds of different data types appear. You might consider just experimenting with different file sizes to see how much it can bear.

Comment: @icktoofay: IMO your comment is complete enough to be an answer. (+1)

Comment: @icktoofay thats the parameters mentioned but how to get the value if i am using 64 bit python3 and loading a json file to the dictionary variable an then processing that dictionary variable.

Comment: @AnkushAbbi: In that case, we know #2, but there’s still #1, #3, and other variables to be considered. Your best bet is to experiment.

Comment: @icktoofay means i will have to wait to get the error. anyways thanks for the assistance.